# How to integrate Flash Professional and Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, workflow, integration, flash-builder

I'm an AS3 developer used to working with Flash Builder. I'm working with a designer who's using Flash Professional to design sprites and backgrounds for a game. I'm looking to create an integrated workflow for us, so they can layout levels in Flash Pro and I can add events in Flash Builder.

As well as triggering events when the player collides with items, triggering animations etc., I'm also looking to switch between scenes when the player changes level and the game changes state (start menu, in-play, game over etc.). To do this I'd like to load everything into Flash Builder and manipulate it programatically - showing and hiding scenes, scrolling, checking for collisions etc.

I've found guides to exporting a swc from Flash Pro and accessing the library in Flash Builder, but this only gives me the classes, not the positioned instances of objects. Is it possible to access everything on the stage as I'm looking to do?

This seems like an obvious workflow but I'm not finding it clear how it's done. Is my approach correct, or is there a better way to do this? Any advice on how to setup this workflow generally, what to do or avoid? More specifically, how can I access the entities on the stage and switch between scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile your project in Flash CS into swf and then use `Loader` or `SWFLoader` in Flash Builder to add it to your displaylist.
Also you can wrap all your objects on the stage into one MovieClip and compile it into swc and then use as library.

Comment: This would let me access everything inside the one MovieClip individually (scenes, sprites etc.), plus their positions?

Comment: Right, if you give "instance name" to them

Comment: Do you know how I can attach properties to the MovieClips and read them in Flash Builder?

Comment: What properties? Just some data or displayobjects?

Comment: Just some data. I have graphics (sprites?) on the stage in Flash Professional that I'd like to add attributes to (like 'score = 50', that kind of thing).

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any experience of writing code in Flash CS, but I know, that you can add code to graphical elements, that you create.